# as3 calling an Event function without an event?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function, events

I have the following function first called with a button click.

```
function chooseRosaryIN(evt:Event)
{
    TweenLite.to(chooseRosary, 3, {y:chooseRosaryY,  ease:Cubic.easeOut});
}
```

Later, if I want to call that same function as a regular function call how do I do that? Can it be done? for example if I call this chooseRosaryIN();

I get this error:
**Scene 1, Layer 'Functions', Frame 1, Line 227 1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1.**

I would rather not code two functions just to call this tween. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change requested argument to null :

```
function chooseRosaryIN(evt:Event = null) {
    TweenLite.to(chooseRosary, 3, {y:chooseRosaryY,  ease:Cubic.easeOut});
}
```

You can also use '... args' :

```
function chooseRosaryIN(... args) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer. This code also works. I can call it and just add a "null" in the function.

```
function chooseRosaryIN(evt:Event) 
    {
    TweenLite.to(chooseRosary, 3, {y:chooseRosaryY,  ease:Cubic.easeOut});
    }
chooseRosaryIN(null); /// WORKS without an event call. :)
```

Answer found on this page: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=179842

Comment: but You still have to put this parameter to function .